# Run a section of AWS userdata as ec2-user

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh-agent

I am trying to pull some git repos in my EC2 userdata, but want to pull them as ec2-user rather than root.
As I dont want the private key on the disk I am using ssh-agent to load a key from Parameter Store

However when I try and switch to ec2-user it instantly switches back to root

```
+ sudo su - ec2-user
+ whoami
root
```

I know I can do things like

```
su ec2-user bash -c "whoami"
```

But that only executes that command as ec2-user and I need to execute several (ssh-agent, ssh-add, ssh-keyscan, git clone)

How can I do this without cat'ing my commands to a script and running that?

Comment: I ran your commands and after `whoami` I get `ec2-user`. What AMI are using to launch your instance (AMI ID) and in which region? I would like to launch my own instance and try it out myself.

Comment: I am using a company baked AMI based on the Market Place Centos 7 AMI.  That I know of no user faffing takes place in the baking

Comment: Most CentOS 7 AMIs on AWS use `centos` as the default user and **NOT** `ec2-user`. I launched a test instance using the CentOS 7 AMI from the marketplace and the default user is also `centos`. Either way, the commands still behave as expected in CentOS 7...Sadly I have no idea what could be causing this or how to even investigate it :(